# Can MySQL handle mixed old and new style passwords

Tags: mysql

We migrated our databases to a new server, which unfortunately had a default setting of old_passwords=1.

Because we use PASSWORD() from PHP for some functionality, the newer passwords for those applications, and ofcourse the newly created mysql root and other users all have old style passwords.

I would like to move back to new style passwords in order for the user accounts from before the migration to work again, but I also would like the newly created users to be able to log in still.

Reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-hashing.html it seems that >4.1 servers will handle both old and new style passwords, but I would like to have some confirmation that I am reading that information correctly before I remove that line from my my.cnf, restart the server and end up in a lot of trouble

Comment: Just to clarify, the passwords being created now are 16-byte passwords from before 4.1 and you would like to use 41-byte as the default however you are wonder if mysql will still authenticate the old users if you turn off the old_password switch?

Comment: yes, so the ones created after the migration will work, as will the ones from before the migration who are now broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have read it is pretty clear:

> 4.1 and later clients can authenticate using accounts that have short or long hashes.

But just make sure all your clients are also 4.1 or later. Otherwise if a pre-4.1 user changes their password, they will be locked out.

> Without the --old-passwords option, the following undesirable scenario
>   is possible:
>
> - An old client connects to an account that has a short password hash.
> - The client changes its own password. Without --old-passwords, this
>     results in the account having a long password hash.
> - The next time the old client attempts to connect to the account, it
>     cannot, because the account has a long password hash that requires the
>     new hashing mechanism during authentication. (Once an account has a
>     long password hash in the user table, only 4.1 and later clients can
>     authenticate for it, because pre-4.1 clients do not understand long
>     hashes.)